# How to add a Data Key Column to a Data Table or a List and bind it to a Gridview asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a nested gridview, parent gridview uses a data key to bind the data to the child gridview.

I had only one column in my parent gridview until now. So I was binding the data to the parent Gridview the following way.

```
GridView1.DataSource = id.Select(oid1 => new { id1 }).ToList(); // id1 is the datakey
```

However, now I have two columns namely "ID" and "Count of ID".

If I store the values in a list and try to display them in the gridview. It is not able to bind the data to the child gridview. I think its because it is not recognizing Data Key. Although I am specifying the name very precisely.

I am storing the values in list and Gridview the following way.

```
public class results
    {
        public string id1 { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }

    }

List<results> res = new List<results>();
results r= new results();
r.id1="XXSSDD";
r.count=5;
res.Add(r);
Gridview1.DataSource=res;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Also, id is stored in a hashset and I would like to keep it that way.

Thanks.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How are you binding the list to the gridView, are you using the same way? Please what you are doing now.

Comment: make sure your properties are public that may be your issue. debug and make sure you can see the fields in the list.

Comment: Is this a list on object or a list you creating from parts of a object, I do not under stand can you edit your questions and add how you creating the list?

Comment: Hey. I updated my question for you.

Comment: try Gridview1.DataBind() after you assign the DataSource.

Comment: Already id that still not working.

Comment: and you are doing the binding in Page_Load seeing as it is ASP.net correct

Comment: All this is in a button actually